# 'msg' is undefined error Mirth

Tags: mirth

I am getting an error `msg` is not defined when trying to loop through different `OBX` segments. In my destination DB Writer I have the code
 `var msg = channelMap.get('msg');`
 but how to store the `msg` in the transformer with 
 `channelMap.put('msg', msg`)?

This is what I have currently in the transformer(javascript mapper):

```
var message = message.getRawData();

channelMap.put('msg', message);
```

In destination DB writer:

```
var msg = channelMap.get('msg');
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRawData" of undefined;

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you need a raw message in HL7v2 format in the first place (i.e. in the source transformer)? The global "msg" variable in the destination transformer is already defined and contains an XML representation of your incoming HL7v2 message. You can use it to loop through OBX segments, but your code sample does something different.

Comment: So without using these steps mentioned above if I directly write       if(msg['OBX']['OBX.3']['OBX.3.1'].toString() = '11289-6')
 {
    INITIAL_TEMPERATURE = msg['OBX']['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'].toString();
 }                                                 then I am getting an error 'msg' is undefined.

Comment: You are assigning not comparing values. Try this: `var INITIAL_TEMPERATURE; if('11289-6' == msg['OBX']['OBX.3']['OBX.3.1'].toString()) {INITIAL_TEMPERATURE = msg['OBX']['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'].toString();}`

Comment: In the destination DB writer msg will not be accessible and you dont need to store the incoming message in channel map as well. You can use connectorMessage.getRawData() at the destination DB writer instead of using msg

Comment: @jessica you can ask this question on mirth forum where you can share your exported channel and others can help by looking at the code.

Answer (score -3):

On the source connector filters and transformers, msg is a given variable, you can't (and should not) declare it (var msg) and is not on the channelMap to be able to get it (channelMap.get('msg')), you just use it: msg[...].

On the destination you can get the message without putting it on the channelMap.